# Is there a way to know when the stage is moved in Java FX?

Tags: javafx-8

In my application, I have the need to open a stage in the last place that it existed.

Currently I have implemented the saving of the location like so:

```
stage.setOnHidden(event -> {
        PositionDTO dto = new PositionDTO();
        dto.setHeight(stage.getHeight());
        dto.setWidth(stage.getWidth());
        dto.setX(stage.getX());
        dto.setY(stage.getY());
        //save the position to either a file or database...
    });
```

However, I am wondering if there is a way to set that value when the user drags the window(stage) to a new location since they can open this stage more than one at a time, and opening in the same spot is what the users want.  They may not have closed the first one that was opened?

I can't seem to find an event I can listen for.

Thanks!

Comment: Register listeners with [`xProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#xProperty) and [`yProperty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#yProperty)?

Comment: Wouldn't storing the details to a file or database really be overwhelmed as that event is called repeatedly while moving?  I was hoping for something that notified when it stopped moving. Unless there is a way to know when it stopped?

Answer (score 0):

This is one option for detecting whether or not the Stage has stopped moving so that you can record the location of its X and Y position:

```
double thisX = 0;
double thisY = 0;

private boolean windowStoppedMoving() {
    boolean windowStoppedMoving = false;
    try {
        double x = thisX;
        double y = thisY;
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        boolean xNotChanged = x == thisX;
        boolean yNotChanged = y == thisY;
        windowStoppedMoving = yNotChanged && xNotChanged;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return windowStoppedMoving;
}
```

Then you register a ChangeListener on the Scene Window xProperty and yProperty:

```
scene.getWindow().xProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    thisX = (double) newValue;
    new Thread(() -> {
        if (windowStoppedMoving()) {
            double finalXValue = thisX;
            double finalYValue = thisY;
        }
    }).start();
});

scene.getWindow().yProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    thisY = (double) newValue;
});
```

As the user is dragging the window around the screen, the xProperty ChangeListener sets thisX to the newValue each time it is called, then it fires off a thread, while the yProperty is simply setting the value of thisY each time it is called. The thread starts by recording the value of thisX and thisY, then it waits for 2 seconds and if those values have not changed, it returns true.

It works quite well and only returns one true result after the window stops moving.